# Embed de Bootstrap no se ve

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, responsive

Estoy intentando poner un vídeo de youtube y hacerlo **responsive** con el código de **Bootstrap** como aparece aquí: [Embeds](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/).

El caso es que yo lo tengo dentro de un `tab` de **bootstrap**, y cuando le doy a la pestaña para mostrar el vídeo, este no aparece, ni siquiera ocupa espacio..

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

¿Qué se me está pasando?

Comment: Armé un snippet de [Codepen](https://codepen.io/cristiancajiaos/pen/MWWPjdR) con tu código y con el ejemplo básico de [pestañas de Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs) (de hecho el código del `.tab-pane` que tienes en tu pregunta, pertenece al segundo elemento en el contenedor `.tab-content` en el ejemplo que se muestra), y a juzgar por ello, no pasa lo que describes. ¿Puedes poner todo el código de pestañas para verlo más en detalle? (esto es, pestañas y contenido)

Comment: Tambien puedes revisar la consola del navegador a ver que puede estar pasando con los elementos.

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto a los estilos, si pones ese mismo código sin cargar bootstrap si aparece.

Con bootstrap 4 (sólo el CSS) ya no se ve, en el inspector de propiedades, sobre el contenedor principal se esta aplicando:

```
.fade:not(.show) {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

ese estilo impide que se vea tu vídeo. Podrías reescribirlo, para que aparezca:

```
.fade:not(.show) {
    opacity: inherit;
}
```

*Nota:* no se si cargas también el JS de *bootstrap* y si esto le afecta o tienes otros estilos, anidamientos que lo hagan, con ese código, la solución funciona, es decir que el vídeo o al menos su imagen de cubierta aparece, que no se reproduce.

Ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style type="text/css">
    .fade:not(.show) {
        opacity: inherit;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
        <h3> Prueba </h3>
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```